# Style item name not being recognized despite being used in Android's own styles.xml

Tags: android, styling, theming

Here's a resource of mine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="MyTheme">
    <item name="editTextStyle">@android:style/Widget.EditText</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Eclipse doesn't like it: "No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'editTextStyle'"

At the same time, if I open Android's own `platforms/android-3/data/res/values/themes.xml`, I see that this is clearly being used there:

```
<resources>
...
  <style name="Theme">
    ...
    <item name="editTextStyle">@android:style/Widget.EditText</item>
    ...
```

Android documentation encourages to read that very same file to learn about the ins and outs of styling. But how can I actually do the same cool things they do there?

Comment: When your reference R.attr.editTextStyle make sure it references your projects R file and not the android one. Check your imports for Android.R . If its there remove it

Comment: Clean your project and run again.. this will generate R file again..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the `android` namespace:

```
 <item name="android:editTextStyle">@android:style/Widget.EditText</item>
```

Also, you probably only want to list the items you are overriding, there is really no point in setting it to the default.